# MySQL 8x LOAD XML doesn't import Data

Tags: mysql, xml

I am using MySQL 8 Community Edition and I want to import a `mysqldump` exported XML File into the Database. I know it is not possible to load the whole Database but it seems to be possible to load the single Tables which is not nice but is a way to import the Data.

My XML File looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mysqldump xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<database name="wiki">
    <table_structure name="archive">
        <field Field="ar_id" Type="int(10) unsigned" Null="NO" Key="PRI" Extra="auto_increment" Comment="" />
        <field Field="ar_namespace" Type="int(11)" Null="NO" Key="MUL" Default="0" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <field Field="ar_title" Type="varbinary(255)" Null="NO" Key="" Default="" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <field Field="ar_comment" Type="varbinary(767)" Null="NO" Key="" Default="" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <field Field="ar_comment_id" Type="bigint(20) unsigned" Null="NO" Key="" Default="0" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <field Field="ar_user" Type="int(10) unsigned" Null="NO" Key="" Default="0" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <field Field="ar_user_text" Type="varbinary(255)" Null="NO" Key="MUL" Default="" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <field Field="ar_actor" Type="bigint(20) unsigned" Null="NO" Key="MUL" Default="0" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <field Field="ar_timestamp" Type="binary(14)" Null="NO" Key="" Default="" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <field Field="ar_minor_edit" Type="tinyint(4)" Null="NO" Key="" Default="0" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <field Field="ar_rev_id" Type="int(10) unsigned" Null="NO" Key="MUL" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <field Field="ar_text_id" Type="int(10) unsigned" Null="NO" Key="" Default="0" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <field Field="ar_deleted" Type="tinyint(3) unsigned" Null="NO" Key="" Default="0" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <field Field="ar_len" Type="int(10) unsigned" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <field Field="ar_page_id" Type="int(10) unsigned" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <field Field="ar_parent_id" Type="int(10) unsigned" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <field Field="ar_sha1" Type="varbinary(32)" Null="NO" Key="" Default="" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <field Field="ar_content_model" Type="varbinary(32)" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <field Field="ar_content_format" Type="varbinary(64)" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <key Table="archive" Non_unique="0" Key_name="PRIMARY" Seq_in_index="1" Column_name="ar_id" Collation="A" Cardinality="38" Null="" Index_type="BTREE" Comment="" Index_comment="" />
        <key Table="archive" Non_unique="1" Key_name="name_title_timestamp" Seq_in_index="1" Column_name="ar_namespace" Collation="A" Cardinality="5" Null="" Index_type="BTREE" Comment="" Index_comment="" />
        <key Table="archive" Non_unique="1" Key_name="name_title_timestamp" Seq_in_index="2" Column_name="ar_title" Collation="A" Cardinality="38" Null="" Index_type="BTREE" Comment="" Index_comment="" />
        <key Table="archive" Non_unique="1" Key_name="name_title_timestamp" Seq_in_index="3" Column_name="ar_timestamp" Collation="A" Cardinality="38" Null="" Index_type="BTREE" Comment="" Index_comment="" />
        <key Table="archive" Non_unique="1" Key_name="usertext_timestamp" Seq_in_index="1" Column_name="ar_user_text" Collation="A" Cardinality="19" Null="" Index_type="BTREE" Comment="" Index_comment="" />
        <key Table="archive" Non_unique="1" Key_name="usertext_timestamp" Seq_in_index="2" Column_name="ar_timestamp" Collation="A" Cardinality="38" Null="" Index_type="BTREE" Comment="" Index_comment="" />
        <key Table="archive" Non_unique="1" Key_name="ar_revid" Seq_in_index="1" Column_name="ar_rev_id" Collation="A" Cardinality="38" Null="" Index_type="BTREE" Comment="" Index_comment="" />
        <key Table="archive" Non_unique="1" Key_name="ar_actor_timestamp" Seq_in_index="1" Column_name="ar_actor" Collation="A" Cardinality="2" Null="" Index_type="BTREE" Comment="" Index_comment="" />
        <key Table="archive" Non_unique="1" Key_name="ar_actor_timestamp" Seq_in_index="2" Column_name="ar_timestamp" Collation="A" Cardinality="38" Null="" Index_type="BTREE" Comment="" Index_comment="" />
        <options Name="archive" Engine="InnoDB" Version="10" Row_format="Compact" Rows="38" Avg_row_length="431" Data_length="16384" Max_data_length="0" Index_length="65536" Data_free="0" Auto_increment="43" Create_time="2018-06-28 22:27:58" Collation="binary" Create_options="" Comment="" />
    </table_structure>
    <table_data name="archive">
    <row>
        <field name="ar_id">1</field>
        <field name="ar_namespace">0</field>
        <field name="ar_title">AGENT</field>
        <field name="ar_comment">Created page</field>
        <field name="ar_comment_id">0</field>
        <field name="ar_user">0</field>
        <field name="ar_user_text">10.150.2.206</field>
        <field name="ar_actor">0</field>
        <field name="ar_timestamp">20150320104321</field>
        <field name="ar_minor_edit">0</field>
        <field name="ar_rev_id">93</field>
        <field name="ar_text_id">93</field>
        <field name="ar_deleted">0</field>
        <field name="ar_len">17</field>
        <field name="ar_page_id">23</field>
        <field name="ar_parent_id">0</field>
        <field name="ar_sha1">3sjhif41h53b3223hfeyx59wv52ic</field>
        <field name="ar_content_model" xsi:nil="true" />
        <field name="ar_content_format" xsi:nil="true" />
    </row>
    </table_data>
</database>
</mysqldump>
```

The SQL Statement in MySQL Workbench looks like:

```
LOAD XML INFILE 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\db_backup.xml'
   INTO TABLE wiki.archive ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<ar_id>';
```

Unfortunetly the Result ends in `0 row(s) affected Records: 0  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0`. I also changed to differend Charsets but no success.

If someone knows what could be the Issue here any help would be appreciated.

I thought the XML Format is maybe wrong but on the MySQL 8 Documentation Page they mention `mysqldump` ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-xml.html ).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the `ROWS IDENTIFIED BY` doesn't need the PK it needs the Tag in the XML File which reflects the Rwos for the Data. In this case it should be `row`.

If I execute:

```
LOAD XML INFILE 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\db_backup.xml'
   INTO TABLE wiki.archive ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<row>';
```

It results in `1 row(s) affected Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0`.

Unfortunetly I need to remove all other Tables from the XML File.